# differential chain rule

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I'm trying to follow some calculus [lecture notes](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wmo5g2lfb599hwsulnees/Matrix-Calculus.pdf?rlkey=n9xll4xlref9n6lrr3zsmiv12&e=1&dl=0) and I can reproduce an argument for the sum and product rule. Can I make an argument like this for the chain rule in a similar style, using the definition of $df$?

$$
df := f(x+dx) - f(x)
$$

#### Sum rule

$$
f(x) := g(x) + h(x) 
$$

\begin{align}
df 
&= f(x+dx) - f(x) \\
&= g(x+dx)+h(x+dx)-(g(x)+h(x)) \\
&= dg + g(x) + dh + h(x) - g(x) - h(x) \\
&= dg + dh
\end{align}
where step (3) uses $dg=g(x+dx)-g(x)$ and likewise for $dh$.

#### Product rule

$$f(x) := g(x)h(x)$$

\begin{align}
df
&= f(x+dx) - f(x) \\
&= g(x+dx)h(x+dx) - g(x)h(x) \\
&= (dg + g(x))(dh+h(x)) - g(x)h(x) \\
&= dgdh + dgh + gdh + gh - gh \\
&= dgdh + dgh + gdh \\
&= dgh + gdh
\end{align}

using the same rewrite as above.

#### Chain rule

$$f(x) := g(h(x))$$

\begin{align}
df
&= f(x+dx)-f(x) \\
&= g(h(x+dx)) - g(h(x)) \\
&= g(dh + h(x)) - g(h(x)) \\
&= \quad ?
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:
(Assuming that the derivative of $f$, $f^\prime$ is defined as $\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}$.)
$$
df=f(x+dx)-f(x) \\
=g(h(x+dx))-g(h(x)) \\
=g(h(x)+dh)-g(h(x)) \\
=\frac{g(h(x)+dh)-g(h(x))}{dh}dh \\
=g^\prime(h(x))dh.
$$

Comment: $ = g′(h(x))h′(x)dx$, I suppose.